# DRF Return 201 if user has not voted and 400 if voted

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need to make simple API where I am sending a form that creates a vote instance and return 201 status code, but if user have already voted it returns 400 bad request.

my models looks like:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    short_name = models.CharField(max_length=24)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.short_name}"


class Vote(models.Model):
    voter = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_voted = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id}/{self.voter}"
```

`views.py`:

```
class VoteView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Vote.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TaskCreateSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = self.request.user
            voter = Company.objects.get(user=user)
            has_voted = Vote.objects.filter(voter=voter)
            serializer.save(voter=voter)
```

and `serializers`

```
class TaskCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Vote
        fields = [
        ]
```

For now it just always returns 201. I am looking for a way where I can write logic that can check if Vote instance for current user exists then return `Response(data={"message":"You have already voted"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)`. The simplest way.

Comment: how do you track that a user has already voted? it looks like you're only tracking `Company` votes.

Comment: Yeah and I want to check if there is a vote from a Company instance if it exists return 400

Comment: Then why don't you just set `unique=True` on the `voter` field? That will make a new vote with the same company invalid when the serializer validates the data.

Comment: Then it returns Django Integrity Error

Comment: the thing is I don't see how the code you're showing us works in the first place, because your serializer has no fields whatsoever so it isn't serialising anything and is always valid.. But you can't save a `Vote` without a `voter` and nowhere you're actually setting the `voter`. You get the "integrity" error when?

Comment: I have editted my post check `perform_create` method that assign a `voter` as currently logged in user

Comment: then why not check if `has_voted` contains something before saving?

Comment: I have actually done it with `return Response(data={"message":"You have already voted"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)` but it anyway always responsed 201. Like it was ignoring my `if`

Comment: look at [this](http://www.cdrf.co/3.9/rest_framework.generics/CreateAPIView.html). You'll see that `create()` just calls `perform_create()` without expecting any return value. You need to override `create()`

Comment: Wow thanks now everything works as expected.